# JsonObject within array volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley

My Post Data is this,

```
[
  {
    "LAT" : "23.04519585271151",
    "LONG" : "57.03520084051642"
  }
]
```

my result is this

```
{"result":"success"}
```

I am using volley to achieve this post request below is my code,

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(BottomSheetActivity.this);
    JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    postparams.put("LAT", "23.04519585271151");
    postparams.put("LONG", "57.03520084051642");
    jsonArray.put(postparams);

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonArray,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
        });

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

after I am running error block will run why I got error.
        I don't know why error only i got give solution to solve this. I am 
        unfortunately get no result,now also I am trying this help to solve
        me this.

Error Log

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"success"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Add error log in question.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"sucess."} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: what's jsonArray when you are creating request object

Comment: now i edit and correct my code

Answer (score 0):

What you getting in response is JsonObject. You are trying to convert that into JSONArray and its throwing exception.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        url, jsonArray,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
```

Above Change JsonArrayRequest to **JsonObjectRequest**

Comment: i am using JsonObjectRequest also but here  also error part only run but

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I don't understand from the code your were publishing.....

1 - `postparams` object is never used.....?
2 - Where is the declaration of `jsonArray`?

Apart from that, I see two problems with the type of :

a) First of all, the data your should be sending (by POST) is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject:

```
JSONArray postDataJsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
postparams.put("LAT", "23.04519585271151");
postparams.put("LONG", "57.03520084051642");
postDataJsonArray.put(postparams);
```

b) The response is a JSONObject and not a JSONArray:(In fact, that's the error the log is telling you), so instead of using JsonArrayRequest, use a CustomRequest or a JSONObjectRequest

Comment: Ok, so now the problem is as I told u with using the JsonArrayRequest. You should better use JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest instead of             JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST)

Comment: i am also using JsonObjectRequest. but this case error part will run.but i toast error.getMessage(); it is null. what will do

Comment: Ok, that's a different thing. Thats the answer from the server, but from the Android point of view everything is ok